# How to display only even position items in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I am getting data from Database and displaying using a custom `list adapter` in a ListView. I need to display only even position items in ListView.

i am able to solve this in two ways.

`1.` sorting data before attaching to adapter, but i want to do those task in `getView()` method of adapter/by using other available methods in adapter.

`2.`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{
   if( position%2 == 0 ) {
      // display
   } else {
      // not display
   }
return view;
```

in this i am getting alternate view's are empty view's.. i want to avoid these empty view.

i ant to do those all calculations in `getView()` method, without empty view in the ListView. How i can do this?

Comment: No, just no. Filter the `List` and then pass it to the `Adapter`. Don't try to abuse `Adapter`s for things they weren't designed for. When `getView()` is called it is literally to late to do what you want. `getView()` is called because the `ListView` needs a `View` for the item at the supplied position. There is no way to say that you don't want to display this item, as it already needs to be displayed. Any workarounds would just be brittle hacks which try to make `Adapter`s do what they are not supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to create new List with filtered data and use it in your adapter. Still if you want an alternate solution you can try below code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
     int halfCountOfList = itemList.size()/2;
     // Add +1 in halfCountOfList if itemList size is odd.
     int finalCount = halfCountOfList + itemList.size()%2;
     return finalCount;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

    Item item = getItem(position*2);
    //No need to to check for even item

    return view;
}
```

Comment: this is work..thank you. can you tell me how this is working `return mScreenList.size()/2 + mScreenList.size()%2;` if i try to increase the size * 2.. not working .. can you explain .. why ?

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy It's working by always returning half the size of the `List` in `getCount()`. The `+ mScreenList.size()%2` accounts for an uneven amount of items in the `List` - in other words essentially fixing that `size()` is obviously not zero based unlike the position index in `getView()`. In `getView()` the position is multiplied by 2 to subsequently retrieve every second item from the `List`. But as I said in my answer: Don't do this.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy list.size()/2 will half the list size, but if your list size is odd(let's say 5), then list.size()/2 will return 2 but in your case it should be 3 as index start from 0. so extra list.size()%2 will add 1 more count if list size is odd.

Answer (score 1):

## No, **just no**. This is a really bad idea.

Don't do this. It makes no sense. Think about it: `getView()` is called because a `View` for an item is required. It is too late to make any decision about whether this item needs to be displayed in the `ListView` or not, it already has to be displayed. What you are trying to do is simply not how `ListView`s and `Adapter`s are supposed to work.

Just filter the `List` before passing it to the `Adapter`, you can modify the `List` while it is being displayed by exposing it through a getter method on the `Adapter` and then immediately calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Any other solution which deviates from this or tries to make `Adapter`s work like you expect it would just be a brittle hack and should never be used.

---

<sub>PS: Use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`. It's much better.</sub>

Comment: is it possible to implement using RecyclerView ?

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Not the way you want it to work. You again need to filter the `List` before passing it to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, or modify the `List` in the `RecyclerView.Adapter` accompanied with the appropriate `notify...()` calls.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy My point is: What you want to do is not how it is supposed to work. Trying to make it work that way will just have bad consequences.

Comment: is it possible to make like that, if i use any other callback methods in the adapter.. like getItme() .

Comment: Why do you want to implement this? It makes no sense. The `Adapter` is supposed to display the items it is given. That the `Adapter` has items which need to be displayed and other which don't is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you give a `ListView` adapter a set of data to display, it's going to try to call `getView()` on all of the data when it's needed - it doesn't discriminate. The decisions on how to display it are made in the `getView()` function.

The two are options are to either modify the data set, or only provide full-fledged views to your even index-ed values. Unfortunately, there aren't other ways around this.

Answer (score -1):

Make a another list which contains only even position items in it and pass it on adapter. adapter will call getView method for all items present in list.

Comment: already i told the same in question. i want to sort the data in adapter class using adapter callback methods.

Answer (score -2):

make another function in adapter

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // return a value between 0 and (getViewTypeCount - 1)
        return position % 2;
    }
```

After that in GetView() method

```
int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
    case 0:
        layoutResource = ;//Even Item
        break;

    case 1:
        layoutResource = ;//Odd Item
        break;
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to change layout..i want to show only even position items.

Comment: this doesn't change your layout. if you want to show only even position item then manage your code in case 0.

Comment: then what about in case 1.. it will return empty view right ?

Answer (score -2):

**IF** Your data will be of some objectType and the database will return

```
ArrayList<Object>,
```

then you can do this

Eg:-

```
ListView lv;                   // assign this view to some ListView
final List<Object> listResult; //sorted list returned by database
int len = listResult.size();
for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        Object x = listResult.get(i);
        //extract the data you need from the object returned
        lv.add(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: already i told the same in question. i want to sort the data in adapter class using adapter callback methods.

Comment: You can apply same logic in the adapter class for displaying just even rows.